# The shadow of the part of object is not shown - three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEQDD.png)

Hello.
I exported from blender model tree. All it is going well, but there is a problem.
The shadow is reflected on the surface of the trunk, branches and the shadow - no. Perhaps the problem model? (link to the model below, the archive is exported tree.json)

[Link to the archive](https://www.sendspace.com/file/ubn2xx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, model seems to be ok. I think your code in JS is not correct like castShadow is not turn on;

```
castShadow = false;
```

I've downloaded your model and make a scene, here you go [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Freeman555/f14pa7gr).

three.js r.72

Comment: Thank you. This attribute has been specified correctly. The problem was staged by the light in the scene.

Comment: MrFreeman555, I have another problem. Now, with animation. You can consult me by email or skype?

Comment: @SergeiIvankov ok, so just put brand new question.

Comment: here is my question. thank you in advance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417219/animation-in-three-js