# Animation in THREE JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

There is a model with animation. After the introduction of a new system of animation, I did not get it to run. Maybe I'm wrong to set up export? I am attaching files:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/etv0sl

Code:

```
var mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( player );
mixer.addAction( new THREE.AnimationAction( player.geometry.animations[0] ) );

mixer.update( 1000 );
```

Comment: I'm trying to find solution too, but seem that THREE JS is missing api.. :(

Comment: @Sergei Ivankov mark my answer if you think its the solution? Im young and I need the Rep :))

Answer (score 7):

New System works with animation clips (since r74 if im right).
Heres a sample of my Blender exported JSON models.

```
var mixer;
var actions = {};
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( "webgl/models/model.json", function ( geometry, materials ) {

    model = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, materials, false );
    for(var x=0;x<materials.length();x++) materials[x].skinning = true;
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model );

    //idle
    actions.idle = mixer.clipAction(geometry.animations[0]);
    actions.idle.setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat);
    actions.idle.clampWhenFinished = true;
    actions.idle.play();

    //walk
    actions.walk = mixer.clipAction(geometry.animations[1]);
    actions.walk.setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat);
    actions.walk.clampWhenFinished = true;

    scene.add( model );

}
```

Every exported Animation gets stored in the array geometry.animations.
In my example i explicitly know which index is which animation but its also very easy to map it manually by name: (`geometry.animations[x].name`).

In the animation loop you then have to update the mixer regularly
`if(typeof mixer != "undefined") mixer.update(delta);`

Got my infos from http://yomotsu.net/blog/2015/10/31/three-r73-anim.html

Also heres the regarding sourcecode for an animation action: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ab93512c7a44bd98e669592b3db441c04a2057f4/src/animation/AnimationAction.js

The Export from Blender has A LOT of possible snares especially when
using Skeletal mesh animations (!= morphs).

- Scale values of all bones / Armature / mesh should be exactly "1" and
  never ever be touched again :)
  (Keyframes also should only have keying set LocRot)
- "apply modifiers" button while export always caused me distortions
- select only the mesh while exporting (not the armature or bones)

my export settings:
[image: blender three js skeletal export options]

Hope that helps future explorers :)

Comment: after all these years this is still the pain. i managed to make simple model with 3 animation actions, but whenever i try to adopt existing model with all animations in one action - this always goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if(typeof mixer != "undefined") mixer.update(delta);
```

Should be this

```
if(typeof mixer !== "undefined") mixer.update(delta);
```